# jquery - First get request as synchronous and subsequent to be asynchronous

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, asynchronous

I have a usecase where I want my first get request to the server should happen immediately(synchronous way).
Based on this respose, I will show some message . Then I need to poll the same request asynchronously(ajax).
I have the solution for asynchronousm part . But the first operation , how can I achive this in jquery.
Both are same request. Suggest if any other way to achieve this.

```
(function poll() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "server script path",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("polling"+data);
                        if(data.is_running === false){
                            console.log("stop polling");
                            $("#overlay").show();
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: poll,
                    timeout: 2000
                })
            }, 50000);
        })();
```

Thanks,

Comment: ajax requests are inherently asynchronous. Put your ajax call into a function, and call that function immediately and display message. Also if you want to poll, shouldnt you use setInterval instead of setTimeout?

Comment: Even I put my ajax into a method , the call is asynchronous ..right?

Comment: I see, there's a jquery ajax settings property called "async" that you can set to false. It will block the browser until the request completes.

Comment: @JavaUser Why do you need to block until the first request completes? Synchronous XMLHttpRequests are [bad](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) and [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request). Why can't you just show nothing until your first request comes back, at which point you show your message? Note that "immediately" and "synchronous" are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function poll(synchronous) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "server script path",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("polling"+data);
                if(data.is_running === false){
                    console.log("stop polling");
                    $("#overlay").show();
                }
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: poll,
            timeout: 2000,
            async: !synchronous
        })
    }, 50000);
})(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the `async` property to `false` in your first request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your url here",
    type: "GET",
    success: onSuccess,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    complete: poll //this will start your polling
    //Everything else
});
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) about `$.ajax` and its properties. Setting async to false will make it a synchronous request.

Also if you want to poll the server, you should be using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` as Eric Guan mentioned in the comments.

EDIT: On second thought, I see that you call `poll` when the ajax request is completed. This might be better than `setInterval` depending on your use case.